# Design Bayesian Decision Rule

Tags: self-study, bayesian

A person randomly chooses a coin with probability 0.5: Find which coin he chose
according to the outcome of 3 tosses: Tossing coin 1 yields a head with a probability P(X1 = H) = .3 (and
tail with P(X1 = T) = .7). Tossing coin 2 yields a head with a probability P(X2 = H) = .6 (and tail with
P(X2 = T) = .4). You earn $1 if you correctly guessed the coin and $0 otherwise. Design the optimum
decision rule and estimate your average earning.

Hello folks, I have this problem in hand and I want to understand the following :

1. Are P(X1)=P(X2)=0.5?
2. P(H|X1)=0.3 , P(H|X2)=0.7?
3. How does the Decision Table look like in this problem?
4. How to find the average earning?

Comment: This is exact duplicate of another question. It was posted by user with different account name, but if if is your account I encourage you to merge those accounts.

Comment: Yes, I am a different user and asking the same question. The question wasn't completely answered and my comment was removed from that post. Can I please have this question answered here?

Comment: First of all, you didn't comment, but posted it as an *answer*, it was deleted, because it didn't answer the question. If this is a distinct question, please give us more details on what exactly do you want to know and how does it differ from the linked question? What exactly do you mean by "designing the decision rule" in here? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I apologize for posting the comment as an answer. As I am a new user, I was unable to add a comment.

Comment: I read the answer on that post and figured how we can calculate the probabilities and the average income. But they do not talk about the Decision Rule. I want to find out how do I solve the two things in this problem : 1. The Probability of Heads and Tails 2. The Bayesian Decision Rule

Comment: But this is already answered in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: To be specific, in this equation: ()=(|1)(1)+(|2)(2)
How do I calculate P(H|X1), is it 0.3 as given in the question? And is P(X1)=P(X2)=0.5?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe in details what is unclear for you in this problem, so to make a specific question of this, then it could be re-opened and people could answer it. Be specific about what you don't understand in here, where are you lost.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I will do so.

Comment: 1. "A person randomly chooses a coin with probability 0.5" does this not mean that the P(person choosing coin X1 or X2) is 0.5?
2. In the other thread, it is only answered to find the earning if we chose Heads or Tail and our decision is correct. But in the question it is asked to find the average earning. My question is, how to find the average of earnings in this particular problem?

Comment: Also, I have figured out 2&3 from my previous comment. (I would like to first Thank you for helping me out in real-time. I am at home trying to learn these concepts as my school is closed and I have limited help.)

Comment: Maybe you want me to re-open it so that you can answer your question yourself, while others could comment if your solution is correct?